# My google maps looks weird

Tags: google-maps

I have this page here and the google maps looks weird, and when I say weird the information on the map is too big and cuts off (the the information that looks like it in a square word bubble similar to something you would see in a comic book.)

My Question is, how would I move the map over to view the full information

is there away to set a position on the map?

Here is my google maps code:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.ca/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=672+Brant+Street,+Burlington,+ON&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=672+Brant+Street&amp;sll=43.447946,-79.624382&amp;sspn=0.456129,0.876846&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=672+Brant+St,+Burlington,+Ontario+L7R+2G6&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=43.330828,-79.805332&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.ca/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=672+Brant+Street,+Burlington,+ON&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=672+Brant+Street&amp;sll=43.447946,-79.624382&amp;sspn=0.456129,0.876846&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=672+Brant+St,+Burlington,+Ontario+L7R+2G6&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=43.330828,-79.805332" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Thanks,
J

Comment: A bit of context would help here...

Comment: what you want is to change the center maps positn? or to change the marker? i created this demo for us to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/LyLXt/

Comment: I am looking to move the map down more so the information box will fit...is there away to position the map so the information box will not be cut off?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move it down a little.

1. open the "View Larger Map" link
2. resize it to the size you will be using
3. move the map down so there is room for the InfoWindow above the marker.
4. Capture the "Paste link in email or IM"
5. Paste that link in the address bar
6. Get the "embed code" ("Paste HTML to embed in website")
7. Put the embed code in your HTML.

[adjusted jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExWHU/4/)

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.ca/maps?q=672+Brant+Street,+Burlington,+ON&amp;hl=en&amp;sll=43.447946,-79.624382&amp;sspn=0.456129,0.876846&amp;oq=672+Brant+Street&amp;hnear=672+Brant+St,+Burlington,+Ontario+L7R+2G6&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;ll=43.337602,-79.802628&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.ca/maps?q=672+Brant+Street,+Burlington,+ON&amp;hl=en&amp;sll=43.447946,-79.624382&amp;sspn=0.456129,0.876846&amp;oq=672+Brant+Street&amp;hnear=672+Brant+St,+Burlington,+Ontario+L7R+2G6&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;ll=43.337602,-79.802628&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```